# How to convert a Bitmap to a Drawable?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I'm trying to

Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);

not working, I understand that This constructor is deprecated.

advised to use of BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap)

but do not know how to use this constructor

I lay in Resources?

Answer (score 2):

Using context.getResources().  See also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()

Answer (score 0):

Following code helped me.

```
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(imgview.getResoureces,bitmap);
```

where imgview is your target ImageView and bitmap is your required Bitmap.